# Extracting coefficants and variable portion of string (java)

Tags: java, string-parsing

I'm writing a basic polynomial solver, and so far, I've tokenized my input as follows.

Example:
x^2+3.5x+4x+3=0 becomes [x^2,7.5x,3] (call this terms1). I generate this array by separating on "+", and that works well.

I want to extract the coefficients and variables from each of these so it would transform into two arrays like the following:
[x^2,x,""]
[1,7,3]

So far my code looks like this (but it accidentally matches the exponent and doesn't match the x squared which as an implicit coefficient)

```
for(String term : terms1){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(term);
        coff = s.findInLine("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?" );
        var = s.next();
        System.out.println(coff);
        System.out.println(var);
}
```

Comment: can you give `terms1` as well in your code?

Comment: You could just split by `+` or `-` first, then for each term, anything that comes before the `x` is a coefficient.  If there's no number there, read it as `1`.

Comment: @DavidWallace This is what I'm doing to obtain terms1. The variable can be any collection of letters [a-z]. As you said, I want to separate the coefficient from the variable, but I'm not sure how to construct a regex to do so.